# How to show google accounts dialog in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I want to do the login/signup process with google acc in the flutter application. Our backend developer gives me an API to call that and get a link for choosing a google account. That link is like this:

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapi-v1-dare.cloud.atadp.ir%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Flogin%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&client_id=1039193858277-2vkeh4q5nvi69bdfe4sr44boo0itlau5.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=offline&response_type=code&prompt=consent&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email`

When I open this link in my browser, I can choose a google account:

[image: screenshot1]

And when choose account, I get this data:

[image]

I try to use the [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) package but can't find a way to load that link. Can you help me how to do this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's late but maybe help someone. that link is for web apps to login/signup with a Google account. for mobiles, it's another way to need to setup that up in the Google developer console.